# How run trino with multiple workes via docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, trino

[Here](https://github.com/datasapiens/reproducible-examples.git) example about how to run trino with worker ut when set `replicas: 4` in `trino-worker` section I got just one worker. E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM system.runtime.nodes;
```

Outpus:

```
node_id,    http_uri,               node_version, coordinator, state
coordinator,http://172.31.0.2:8080, 392,          true,        active
worker,     http://172.31.0.6:8080, 392,          false,       active
```

In the docker compose there are 4 nodes Oo

Any ideas how attach more than 1 worker to the trino via docker-compose?